# What is a better practice in bash scripts to test if string is empty: [[ -z ${value//[0-9]/""} ]] or ! [[ ${value//[0-9]/""} ]]?

Tags: comparative-review, bash

I test in a bash script if a variable `value` contains digits only.
There are two options, both give the valid results:

```
validate_is_pos_int(){
local value=$1
if ! [[ ${value//[0-9]/""} ]]
then
    return 0 # True; $1 has digits only
else
    return 1 # False; $1 contains other letters besides digits
fi}
```

and the second (maybe more readable):

```
validate_is_pos_int(){
local value=$1
if [[ -z ${value//[0-9]/""} ]]
then
    return 0 # True; $1 has digits only
else
    return 1 # False; $1 contains other letters besides digits
fi}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview@SE. The title describes something else than the code alternatives. Please try and [summarise as the title what the code (not the question) is there for](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). (What is the result of your tests for, say, 42?)